# Filter Nested JSON in PostgreSQL DB

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

```
{
"List1": [
    {
      "f1": "b6ff",
      "f2": "day",
      "f3": "HO",
      "List2": [{"f1": 1.5,"f2": "RATE"}]
    }]
}
```

This is nested JSON in which there's a list 'List2' inside another list 'List1'.

how to filter f1 = 1.5 in List2?  I have tried using @> operator used for contains but it doesn't work with nested JSON.

Comment: Do you want a SQL or a Python solution?

Comment: No, SQL query for postgres DB.

Comment: Do you want to return the element of that array, or just rows that ave one element in that array with that criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using an up-to-date Postgres version and you want to get the rows that fulfill the condition, you can use a JSON path expression:

```
select *
from the_table
where the_column @@ '$.List1[*].List2[*].f1 == 1.5'
```

Alternatively you can use the `@>` operator, but the parameter must match the array structure in the column:

```
where the_column @> '{"List1":[{"List2":[{"f1": 1.5}]}]}';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in `Where` clause to fetch the whole record and then use Python to get that element.

```
SELECT .... WHERE 
dbfieldname #> {'List1', '0', 'List2', '0', 'f1'} = 1.5
```